# find 'name' not the value of variable that holds maximum value matlab

Tags: matlab

Assume we have 30 variables, I am looking for a way to find which value hold the biggest value. I need 'name' of it, not value of it.
for example:

```
I1=10
I2=12
I3=14
I4=90
I5=5
I6=90
```

How can I code a function the return 'I4' and 'I5'. Not return just 90.

One way is to first find the maximum then by comparing each variable we can find out the name of variable. But, this is not efficient if we have a lot of variables. Anybody has an idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use different variables. Use a vector `I = [10 12 14 90 5 90]`. And then `index = find(I==max(I))` will give you `[4 6]`

Comment: why don't you use a single vector instead?

Comment: Please, please, please use a vector. `I(1)` is much easier to use than `I1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use `cell` arrays for this sort of thing, but anyway you could do something like this:

```
names = who('-regexp', 'I[0-9]+');
values = cellfun(@eval, names);
maxValue = max(values);
maxNames = names(values == maxValue)
```